# Can Oracle Heterogeneous Services be used to connect to a SQL Azure database?

Tags: oracle, azure-sql-database

I would like to be able to use a database link from an Oracle 10g database to a [SQL Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/sql-database) database.

Will Oracle Heterogeneous Services support this?

I can [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-python) [various](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/) [articles](https://www.altova.com/Build-ODBC-Connection-String.html) relating to connecting to SQL Azure via ODBC, so does this mean that it will be possible to do it using Oracle HS, or am I oversimplifying things?

Answer (score 1):

If there is an ODBC driver to connect to it, then the Oracle Transparent Gateway for ODBC should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since the IP of a SQL Azure server may change over time then the IP address of a SQL Azure server should not be used to create a DB Link.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo

Comment: Of  course, it's a bad idea to use the _ip address_ in any database link, SQL Azure or not.  The IP of _any_ server is subject to change.  Not as often as a workstation with a DHCP address, but still is possible whenever the net admin deems necessary.  Use the server _name_ and let DNS sort it out.

Comment: Azure SQL uses SNI, IPs changing is the least of your problems when not using hostnames (There are 1-3 fixed IPs per region....)